# How to validate models with a composite keys in ActiveRecord?

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'd like to know if I can write a validation that would validate the uniqueness of a record based on multiple fields. My model has a composite primary key, i.e.

```
field :houseno, :type => String
field :street, :type => String
field :boro, :type => String
```

What would be a good way of validating the uniqueness of this record?

I'm trying to use custom validators like this:

```
class AddressValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:base] << "This address is already in our records." unless check(record)
  end

  private
    def check(record)
      Address.find(:street=>record.street,:houseno=>record.houseno,:boro=>record.boro).length > 0
    end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `scope`:

```
validates :houseno, uniqueness: { scope: [:street, :boro] }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well. You can also express as   validates :houseno, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 6, :allow_blank => false, :allow_nil => true }, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:street, :boro] }